# How is this question on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Where in the solar system is the most viable place to put my colonists, after Mars and Luna?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/after-mars-and-luna-which-is-the-most-viable-place-for-colonization-within-our)

I get that this is a fun question that allows people to contribute and that is why it gets so many votes.  But that question feels like it is totally against the whole spirit of this site.  It is not about world building but rather just a fun question for people to speculate on.  But it really does not belong here.  And if we continue to allow these types of questions this site will become cluttered with the type of nonsense that most internet forums are.  I would hope that is a fate that we want to avoid.

Comment: Would you have the same objection if it were cast as "where in the solar system can I put my colonists to minimize risks to them?"?  That is, are you objecting to the *core question* or to its *packaging*?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I think I would, though in a made up solar system I can see a bit more wiggle than here using the actual real world and solar system.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think your comment nails it.  Without framing it in how it impacts a world building project it is easy to just say...interesting but not appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

The text of the question (at present) is:

> Mars and Earth's moon already feature in a lot of fiction about space colonization. After these two planets, and assuming that other solar systems are too far away, what is the best place within this solar system to colonize?

The first sentence establishes the context of fiction about space colonization, so I think it's pretty clear that this question is asking about building out a fictional scenario.  That's on-topic.  But it could be stronger; it would be better to cast the question not as "which is the most viable place..." but, rather, "where in the solar system can I put my colonists to minimize risks to them?".  That places the emphasis more clearly on the problem to be solved -- I have colonists I want to put somewhere in this solar system.

I don't think the current question is off-topic.  I'm going to propose the edit (of the title) that I've just described here.  (Update: edit accepted.)

Comment: I agree that narrowing it down makes it a better fit. It might lead to a number of questions, narrowed in different ways. One question might be about minimising risks (as you suggest), another might be about maximising return if the colony has to gather materials/energy to pay its way, another might be about the best strategic position to gain most scientific benefit over the coming decades/centuries. A few questions have already benefited from being split into several - I think this would also be a good candidate.

Comment: @githubphagocyte I realized I could just reuse the "viable" phrasing from the original, so that's what I proposed: "Where in the solar system is the most viable place to put my colonists, after Mars and Luna?"

Comment: I managed to only read the content of the question, which just said "best" and missed the "viable" in the title - now that I've read it properly I can see what you mean...

Answer (score 3):

It's on topic - for the simple reason that it's about creation of a setting. If someone is creating a setting involving colonizing the solar system then part of building that world is deciding where would next be colonized...